# Trying to test fetch with mocha & chai using await

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, fetch, chai

I intend to test fatch with mocha. I am using [testing fetch with mocha and chai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467126/testing-fetch-with-mocha-and-chai)
to get started but kept running into multiple errors.

Here is the test code:

```
var jsdom = require('mocha-jsdom')
global.document = jsdom();
const chai = require( 'chai' ).assert;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const chaiHTTP = require("chai-http");
const index = require('../client/js/index');

chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHTTP)

describe('Index', function(){

  it( "renders book data ", async () =>{
        await fetchBooks()
        .then(() => {
          expect(renderBooks).to.have.been.called();
        })
  })
})
```

This throws the following error :

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
```

Probably the selector does not return any elements at the stage when the script is executed. Not sure why.

```
//index.js
function fetchBooks(){
  fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/books`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(renderBooks)
}

const main = document.querySelector('#main')
function renderBooks(data) {
  data.forEach(book => {
    h2.innerHTML = `<h2>${book.name}</h2>`
  })
}
```

Comment: Document is undefined?

Comment: Which document?

Comment: `document.querySelector` this one

Comment: It is defined, works perfectly.

Comment: That’s not what the error you’ve posted says.

Comment: how do I test it?

Comment: I’m confused what you’re testing? Are you trying to test the API endpoint? or are you testing fetch itself?

Comment: Fetch, is it not the correct way of testing a fetch? @evolutionxbox

Comment: Why are you testing fetch?

Comment: It's part of an assignment, I was asked to write a test for every function I wrote. I assumed I might have to write it for fetch as well.

Comment: I can’t speak for your tutor, but I would not test fetch itself, but instead the custom function using it. Fetch is a native JS method.

Comment: Do you mean the fetchBooks() function where I'm fetching the API? @evolutionxbox

Comment: yes. `index.js` isn’t being used in the tests. Try calling `fetchBooks` in the test?

Comment: describe('Index', function(){

  it( "renders book data ", async () =>{
        await fetchBooks()
        .then(() => {
          expect(renderBooks).to.have.been.called();
        })
  })
})

Comment: Still receiving the same error :(

Comment: Edited the test code above as well.

Comment: The promise needs to be returned in `fetchBooks` for `then` to be used. Where is `renderBooks` defined in the test? Where are you spying on `renderBooks`?

Comment: I am not sure, where I'm supposed to define `renderBooks` in the test. I thought it's being imported from the index.js file. And what is spying? Actually this is the very first time I'm writing a test for my code, so there're lots of things I don't know about testing yet.

Comment: There’s a few things you probably should read up on as it could take a while for me to explain in the comments. 1-ES imports/exports. 2-Spies

Comment: Thanks! @evolutionxbox